# iframe's html content not visible in Edge and Internet explorer

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer, iframe, microsoft-edge

This is my angular app's code

```
<div class="with-border" layout="column" flex>
            <iframe class="no-pointer-events" flex ng-attr-srcdoc="{{vm.campaign.body | toTrustedHTML}}" width="100%" frameborder="0" sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin allow-top-navigation"></iframe>
</div>
```

It is working fine in all browsers except IE and Edge.

Comment: set up IE to record blocked content, xss and security errors and warnings. Tools>Internet Options>Advanced tab, check "Always record developer console messages".
Load your test/production site in IE.... Use the File>Properties menu to determine which IE security zone your test/production site maps to.. expected internet. Press F12 to display the dev tool... it will now show warnings and errors for blocked content. Use the DOM Explorer tab of the dev tool to examine the 'computed' page source... (not angular) source  check that IE's ActiveX filtering is turned on or off.

Comment: Include links to your website or a jsfiddle mashup with your questions.

Comment: It doesn't show any warnings or error messages in console. I cant share link  it's a paid app.

Answer (score 0):

IE and Edge do not support `srcdoc` attribute. 
You can check it here: 
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_srcdoc.asp
You can use `src` attribute for those browsers, but don't forget that for dynamic values and bindings you should use `ng-src`